# php ajax page output

Tags: php, ajax

in my case , i need to return value from a ajax page. as i know , there is two way to do it: echo , return.

```
echo 0;
exit;
```

or

```
return 0;
exit;
```

is there any different between them?

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would use :

```
echo '0'; 
exit();
```

Why ? Because you don't want to output an integer (treated as bool in PHP, I assume 0/1). You want a string so AJAX can read it.

Return is for function and stuff, **not to end a page**.

Comment: You can echo the integer 0 and it will show up just the same as the string '0'. If you `echo false`, however, nothing shows up in the output. Still, I suppose it is safest to always echo as a string to ensure that extra data isn't truncated, like `echo 1.0`, which would just echo '1' and leave off the '.0'.

Comment: Yes, true. But it is only a "principle". PHP threat 0 and 1 as false and true respectively. An HTML page must be treated as a giant string and not an integer. This is why I suggest using `echo '0';` even if the output is the same;

Answer (score 0):

AJAX retrieves the output from another page. `echo` will output something, but `return` is for returning a value from a function.

Use `echo`.